# Objective C : Method call query

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4

I'm a newbie to Objective C and iOS. Till now I have made simple apps for initial hands on.
I was going through one of the examples in the net but unable to understand the implementation of method call in the code

below is method call

```
[db addObserver:(DBObserver*)self];
```

I understand that 'db' object is calling a method 'addObserver' with an argument. But what does 'self' signifies here. Got bit confused with argument.

I'm extremely sorry for such dumb question, but consider me as beginner in iOS and Objective C

Comment: Did you try searching first?

Comment: Yes, but my i got confused with (DBObserver*)self. I know the self keyword, but i was not able relate the concept in the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context the statement:

```
[db addObserver:(DBObserver*)self];
```

Means "add **me** (`self`) as an observer of the `db` object".

However it doesn't appear to be Key Value Observing ([KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)) as that has a different method signature, so it must some other implementation of the Observer Pattern.

**UPDATE** I suspect the cast to `DBObserver *` is unncessary, but that depends on how that method is declared.

Answer (score 1):

`self` in Objective-C is equals to `this` in C++

Comment: What makes you think the OP knows C++?

Answer (score 1):

`self`  is the same as `this` in `java` or `C++`

Comment: What makes you think the OP knows Java or C++?